# Angularjs: Singleton service using $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

is it possible in angular to create service using $http which will take method, url, success and failure callback as parameters when called from controller.

I want to achieve following kind of functionality using angular.

```
  var ajax = {
            URL: "webservice url",
            loggedIn: false,
            importedId: "",
            token: '',
            userdetails: new Backbone.Collection.extend({}),
            serverCall: function(method, data, successCallBack, failureCallBack) {
                var that = this;
                //console.log(method);
                //console.log(successCallBack);
                that.showLoading();
                $.ajax({
                    url: that.URL + method,
                    method: 'post',
                    data: data,
                   // contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        that.hideLoading();
                        if (that.checkForError(data))
                        {
                            successCallBack(data);
                        }

                    },
                    fail: function(data) {
                        that.hideLoading();
                        failureCallBack(data);
                    }
                });
            }
```

i am using https://github.com/StarterSquad/startersquad.github.com/tree/master/examples/angularjs-requirejs-2 folder structure for app and inside services i have following code

```
define(['./module'], function(services) {
'use strict';
services.factory('user_resources', ['$resource', '$location', function($resource, $location) {

        return $resource("", {},
                {
                    'getAll': {method: "GET", url:'JSON/myList.JSON',isArray:true}

                });
    }]);
});
```

and in controller  i have following code

```
  define(['./module'],    function (controllers) {
'use strict';
controllers.controller('myListCtrl',['Phone','Phone1','loginForm','$scope','$http','user_resources','CreditCard',function(Phone,Phone1,loginForm,$scope,$http,user_resources,CreditCard){
    console.log(user_resources.getAll())
}]);
});
```

which returns [$promise: Object, $resolved: false] how to get data from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also use $resource for this type of usage.

```
angular.module('MyApp.services').
factory('User_Resource',["$resource","$location", function ($resource,$location){
    var baseUrl = $location.protocol()  + "://" + $location.host() + ($location.port() && ":" + $location.port())  + "/";
    return  $resource(baseUrl+'rest/users/beforebar/:id',{}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        get:   { method: 'GET' },
        login: { method: 'POST', url:baseUrl+'rest/users/login'},
        loginAnonymous: { method: 'POST', url:baseUrl+'rest/users/loginAnonymous'},
        logout: { method: 'POST', url:baseUrl+'rest/users/logout/:id'},
        register: { method: 'POST', url:baseUrl+'rest/users/register'}
    });
}]);
```

Example of usage :

```
    userSrv.logout = function(user,successFunction,errorFunction)
    {
        var userSrv = new User_Resource();
        userSrv.$logout({user.id}, //params
            function (data) {   //success
                console.log("User.logout - received");
                console.log(data);
                if (successFunction !=undefined)
                    successFunction(data);
            },
            function (data) {   //failure
                //error handling goes here
                console.log("User.logout - error received");
                console.log(data);
                var errorMessage = "Connexion error";
                if (errorFunction !=undefined)
                    errorFunction(errorMessage);
            });

    }
```

Comment: what is user in userSrv.logout = function(user,successFunction,errorFunction) ?

Comment: You are right, in my first example, it was not useful.
I change my answer in order to let it be clearer.

Comment: [  {
        "age": 0, 
        "id": "1", 
    }, 
    {   "age": 1, 
        "id": "2", 
    }, using this as a json and tried to call services.factory('user_resources', ['$resource', function($resource) {
            return $resource('JSON/myLeaveList.JSON', {}, {
                    query: {method:'GET',isArray:true}
            });
        }]);

Comment: then called it using using userSrv.query = function(user,successFunction,errorFunction)
    {
        var userSrv = new user_resources();
        console.log(userSrv);
        userSrv.$query({}, //params
            function (data) {   //success
                if (successFunction !=undefined)
                    successFunction(data);
            },
            function (data) {   //failure
                if (errorFunction !=undefined)
                    errorFunction(errorMessage);
            });

    } but in console.log(userSrv.query);  it is giving undefined

Answer (score 2):

A service in AngularJS is always a singleton, so you wouldn't have to do anything to achieve that. However, it seems like you do not actually want a singleton as you want to pass in different values. Thus, you might want to add your own service factory function. Something like:

```
function MyHTTPService($rootScope, url, method) {
  this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
  this.url = URL;
  this.method = method;
}
MyHTTPService.prototype.serverCall = function () {
  // do server call, using $http and your URL and Method
};

App.factory('MyHTTPService', function ($injector) {
  return function(url, method) { 
    return $injector.instantiate(MyHTTPService,{ url: url, method: method });
  };
});
```

This can be called using

```
new MyHTTPService("http://my.url.com", "GET");
```

Comment: can you please create fiddle for this? what is MyObjectWithParam?

Comment: Was still a wrong value, I edited the answer. And no, I am not going to create a fiddle for this as I have limited time budget and no-one is paying me to help you (to be honest: I think your request is quite unreasonable as you can create a fiddle on your own).